# Shape file or geojson to database

Tags: java, node.js, spring, geotools

I am trying to read the large shape file and try to find whether  lat and long is in coordinates using geotools

Is there any possible way to store the shape file into database?  Or will store as geojson and retirerive faster to check that lat and long is in coordinates? 
Node js or java which one will have easier implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You can store shape file in MySQL as Spatial Data using ogr2ogr tool.

Read this link:

https://www.igismap.com/insert-shapefile-in-mysql-as-spatial-data/

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but what I understand is that you'll have a Java (Spring Boot) or NodeJS backend.

I haven't experience in developing NodeJS apps, however I do have in Java. My suggestion is that you can achieve it quite fastly that way:

- Use latest version of Spring Boot (2.1.2.RELEASE).
- Use any database supporting Spatial features, e.g. PostgreSQL/PostGIS, Microsoft SQL Server, MySQL, and so on. I suppose you'd also use any NoSQL db.
- Make use of Java Topology Suite (known as JTS) or [Geolatte](http://www.geolatte.org/) frameworks to model your domain objects in Java as Geometries. I've never used Geolatte, but I think it's more powerful than JTS. NEvertheless, JTS has two implementations: vividsolutions' and [locationtech's](https://github.com/locationtech/jts). The former is the legacy version written in 2012 and the latter is the newer one. I always choose latest version of every lirbary, but I can't assure you whether you could pick it, taking into account that JTS dependency is added with Spring Boot.

All in all, I'd choose Spring Boot 2 + JTS and map every geospatial objects as Geometries. You can check my [Gist](https://gist.github.com/russellhoff/54af4abd5862baf86afceb8407ff85e4) on creating geo-objects. Decide which SRID you'll use. Within your Entities, map geo-objects as [Geometry](http://javadox.com/com.vividsolutions/jts/1.13/com/vividsolutions/jts/geom/Geometry.html) data type. Check thw following example:

```
package model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import javax.persistence.ElementCollection;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Singular;

@Entity
@Table(name="stops")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Stop implements Serializable {

    @Transient private static final long serialVersionUID = -2747601079894033016L;

    @Id private String id;
    private String codParada;
    private String tipoExtraido; 
    private String uri;
    private String titulo;
    private Geometry geometria;
    private LocalDateTime ultimaActualizacion;
    @Singular @ElementCollection private List<String> mensajes;
    private String icono;
    private String enlace;
    private String descripcion;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING) private ETipoParada tipo;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to open the [Shapefile](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/data/shape.html) (or GeoJSON) file using a datastore and then to copy the features from that store to a [PostGIS](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/jdbc/postgis.html) (or other [Database](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/jdbc/index.html)) datastore. Just make sure to include the relevant module in your maven pom.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    File inFile = new File("/home/ian/Data/states/states.shp");
    Map<String, Object> outParams = new HashMap<>();
    outParams.put(PostgisNGDataStoreFactory.DBTYPE.key, PostgisNGDataStoreFactory.DBTYPE.sample);
    outParams.put(PostgisNGDataStoreFactory.USER.key, "ian");
    outParams.put(PostgisNGDataStoreFactory.PASSWD.key, "ianian");
    outParams.put(PostgisNGDataStoreFactory.HOST.key, "localhost");
    outParams.put(PostgisNGDataStoreFactory.PORT.key, 5432);
    outParams.put(PostgisNGDataStoreFactory.DATABASE.key, "ian");
    outParams.put(PostgisNGDataStoreFactory.SCHEMA.key, "public");
    // Read
    DataStore inputDataStore = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(
            Collections.singletonMap("url", URLs.fileToUrl(inFile)));

    String inputTypeName = inputDataStore.getTypeNames()[0];
    SimpleFeatureType inputType = inputDataStore.getSchema(inputTypeName);

    FeatureSource<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature>
            source = inputDataStore.getFeatureSource(inputTypeName);

    FeatureCollection<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature>
            inputFeatureCollection = source.getFeatures();

    DataStore newDataStore = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(outParams);


    String typeName = inputTypeName;

    newDataStore.createSchema(inputType);
    SimpleFeatureStore featureStore = (SimpleFeatureStore) newDataStore.getFeatureSource(typeName);

    /*
     * //Optional Filter block //filter String geometryPropertyName =
     * inputType.getGeometryDescriptor().getLocalName();
     * CoordinateReferenceSystem targetCRS =
     * inputType.getGeometryDescriptor().getCoordinateReferenceSystem();
     * 
     * double x1 = 11.5; double y1 = 49.8; double x2 = 12.0; double y2 = 50.1;
     * 
     * ReferencedEnvelope bbox = new ReferencedEnvelope(x1, y1, x2, y2,
     * targetCRS); FilterFactory2 ff = CommonFactoryFinder.getFilterFactory2();
     * Filter filter = ff.bbox(ff.property(geometryPropertyName), bbox);
     */
    // write results
    featureStore.addFeatures(source.getFeatures(/*filter*/));
    //tidy up
    inputDataStore.dispose();
    newDataStore.dispose();
    newDataStore.createSchema(inputType);
    String typeName1 = newDataStore.getTypeNames()[0];

    SimpleFeatureStore featureStore1 = (SimpleFeatureStore) newDataStore.getFeatureSource(typeName1);

    featureStore1.addFeatures(inputFeatureCollection);

    inputDataStore.dispose();
    newDataStore.dispose();
  }
```